# RadioButtonList Model Binding in Asp.Net MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to do model binding for my radio button group , the situation is like this :
whenever I want to check either USD or % radio buttons , in my controller I want to get the true or false value from chosen radio buttons when I press submit the form button, but it appears that View doesn't pass me any value since I set int properties for them in my model. I get all the values from the form except my radio buttons.
I would appreciate any help

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.LstOrderDetails.Count; i++)
   {

      <tr>
       @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderedDiscountAmount) && 
       (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderedDiscountPerc)))
         {
           if(decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderedDiscountAmount), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) != 0M)
         {                                          
           <td class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
             <table style="font-size: 11px;">
               <tr>
                 <td>
                   USD
                 </td>
                 <td>                                                                                                                         @Html.RadioButton(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderDetailID, Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountAmnt, Convert.ToBoolean(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountAmnt))
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderedDiscountAmount, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Discount", style = "font-size: 12px;" })
             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 %
               </td>
                <td>@Html.RadioButton(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderDetailID,Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountPerc, Convert.ToBoolean(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountPerc))
              </td>
              <td>
              </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
      }

      else
      {
        if (decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderedDiscountPerc), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) != 0M)
       {
         removeafterzero = Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderedDiscountPerc.Substring(0, Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderedDiscountPerc.LastIndexOf('.'));

       <td class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
       <table style="font-size: 11px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
         USD
        </td>
        <td>  @Html.RadioButton(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderDetailID, Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountAmnt, Convert.ToBoolean(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountAmnt))
       </td>
       <td rowspan="2">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => removeafterzero, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Discount", style = "font-size: 12px;" })
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
            %
         </td>
         <td> @Html.RadioButton(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderDetailID, Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountPerc, Convert.ToBoolean(Model.LstOrderDetails[i].IsDiscountPerc))
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  }
 }
  }

//Model Part
 public class OrderDetail
    {
       .
       .
       .
        public string OrderedDiscountAmount { get; set; }
        public string OrderedDiscountPerc { get; set; }
        public int IsDiscountPerc { get; set; }
        public int IsDiscountAmnt { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to tie a field to your model you need to use a "for" helper.  try changing your radio button to

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderDetailID, "Dollar")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.LstOrderDetails[i].OrderDetailID, "Percent")
```

since both are tied to the same field, that field will have the value of the selected radio button (Dollar or Percent in this example)